# Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1'

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, configuration, couchbase

```
Aug 10 17:17:34 myhostname sshd[7081]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60018

Aug 10 17:17:42 myhostname sshd[7082]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60019

Aug 10 17:17:43 myhostname sshd[7083]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60020

Aug 10 17:17:50 myhostname sshd[7084]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60021

Aug 10 17:17:51 myhostname sshd[7085]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60022

Aug 10 17:17:58 myhostname sshd[7086]: Bad protocol version identification 'POST /adminport/shutdownTopicRequest HTTP/1.1' from 85.20*.**.** port 60023
```

These are the types of request I get in the auth.log for thousands of ports, in consecutive order, non-stop.

Ideas?

---

UPDATE:: 
It was because of the sshd_config non-standard port and some other services (couchbase) was trying to get to the 22 port. Changed the config of the db and it works.

This is actually a Couchbase bug that loops your ports if it cant't use the standard ports. Can be configured otherwise

Couchbase ports required ::

`9100 Internal index admin port
9101 Internal index scan port
9102 Internal index HTTP port
9103 Internal index build port
9104 Internal index build port
9105 Internal index maintenance
9998 Internal REST port
9999 GSI for internal admin`

Comment: Stop running your ssh server on port 80?

Comment: I'm not. It's running on a custom port, none of the above

Comment: Then stop running it on _that_ port.

Comment: So how am I going to login in if I stop running it?

Comment: I never advised you to stop running it. What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: It has nothing to do with that port. It's trying to go on all ports consecutive, as you can see. It goes ++ on all ports

Comment: That is the _remote_ port on the remote machine, not the local port you chose to run ssh on instead of the correct port (22). You need to change the local port.

Comment: You wore right @MichaelHampton , it was because of a non-standard port.